# Is it possible to regenerate / generate a new identicon?

Tags: discussion

I like the identicon, but sometimes I'm getting tired of the same old shapes / colour.

Is there any way to regenerate / generate a new one with different shapes / colour?

Comment: I believe you have to either get a new IP address or change your email. The point of gravatar is to *identify* you though, so randomly changing it is not easy or advised.

Comment: @Seth The problem it's I'm not even associated in any way to [gravatar.com](http://gravatar.com); I tried to sign up with my SE accounts email address and I didn't get any message about being signed up already, a new profile was created and there's no SE gravatar available in my profile, so I don't think my SE accounts are linked to it

Comment: No, they aren't. You don't. Technically the little squares are called "identicons" and you can't just "generate a new one" on gravatar's site (as I explained above).

Comment: @Seth Sorry I misread this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar). Nevermind.  You're right, [in this case I'd have to change my email address](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37763) or to generate a custom one by myself using the original implementation. But bear with me, being the algorithm publicly available and being unique the identicon generated isn't it a little insecure? Reversing the function to create the identicon one could be able to know my email address, so I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: @Seth Nevermind again, it's a hash of the email, I misread once again. Sorry again.

Answer (score 3):

[This site](http://vksnr.net/identicon.htm) generates SE style identicons using Gravatar; it won't match your own identicon if you are a user recent enough and you are trying to pass your email address because [during its creation for SE a salt has been added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204540).

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the e-mail address associated with your account that will update the identicon to a new pattern.

If you have a gmail account you can use the `+` extension to change the address as far as the identicon is concerned but keep in contact. It has the added advantage that you can set up filtering based on the "to" address for sorting your e-mails.